# PHP Class PDO funciona todo CRUD no servidor local quando sobre pra web so funciona o select

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou com um problema que não consegui resolver. Já pesquisei aqui e não encontrei nada parecido.

Eu tenho uma aplicação em PHP, usando a class PDO para conexão ao banco de dados.
Então eu tenho la o CRUD: `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` E `DELETE`.

Tudo funciona perfeito na minha maquina. No entanto quando eu subo pra o servidor eu não consigo fazer `UPDATE` e nem inserir.

Já vou eliminando as possibilidades: O banco tem todos os privilégios. A versão do PHP é a mesma do meu servidor.

O erro que ele me retorna é essa exception:

```
ERRO AO TENTAR ATUALIZAR ENDEREÃ‡O 
NA LINHA 106, ARQUIVO /home/jdrecargadecartu/public_html/emprestimo/admin/app.dao/EnderecoDao.class.php#0/home/jdrecargadecartu/public_html/emprestimo/admin/app.controllers/UpdateFuncionarioController.php(82): EnderecoDao->editaEndereco(Object(EnderecoModal)) #1 {main}
```

Se alguém poder me ajudar eu agradeço muito.

---

Segue uma das classe que eu chamo todas estao assim:

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Fabio Dias
 * Date: 27/09/14
 * Time: 23:15
 */
include_once "../app.connectionfactory/ConnectionFactory.class.php";
include_once "../app.interface/IEndereco.class.php";

class EnderecoDao implements IEndereco
{
    private $conn;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->conn = ConnectionFactory::getConnection();
    }

    public function cadastraEndereco(EnderecoModal $endereco)
    {
        $id = 0;
        $result = false;
        $rua = $endereco->getRua();
        $numero = $endereco->getNumResidencia();
        $bairro = $endereco->getBairro();
        $complemento = $endereco->getComplemento();
        $cidade = $endereco->getCidade();
        $uf = $endereco->getUf();
        $cep = $endereco->getCep();


        $sqlCadastraEndereco = "INSERT INTO ENDERECO(RUA, NUMERO, COMPLEMENTO, BAIRRO, CIDADE, UF, CEP)  VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $openConn = $this->conn->prepare($sqlCadastraEndereco);
        $openConn->bindParam(1, $rua);
        $openConn->bindParam(2, $numero);
        $openConn->bindParam(3, $complemento);
        $openConn->bindParam(4, $bairro);
        $openConn->bindParam(5, $cidade);
        $openConn->bindParam(6, $uf);
        $openConn->bindParam(7, $cep);

        if($openConn->execute()){

            $count = $openConn->rowCount();


            if($count > 0){
                $id = $this->conn->lastInsertId();
                $endereco->setIdEndereco($id);
                $result = true;
            }
        }else{
            throw new PDOException("ERRO AO CADASTRAR COM O BANCO DE DADOS <br />");
        }



        return $result;
    }

    public function excluiEndereco(EnderecoModal $endereco)
    {
        // TODO: Implement excluiEndereco() method.
    }

    public function listaEndereco()
    {
        // TODO: Implement listaEndereco() method.
    }

    public function editaEndereco(EnderecoModal $endereco)
    {
        $id = $endereco->getIdEndereco();
        $result = false;
        $rua = $endereco->getRua();
        $numero = $endereco->getNumResidencia();
        $bairro = $endereco->getBairro();
        $complemento = $endereco->getComplemento();
        $cidade = $endereco->getCidade();
        $uf = $endereco->getUf();
        $cep = $endereco->getCep();


        $sqlCadastraEndereco = "UPDATE  ENDERECO SET RUA = :rua, NUMERO = :numero, COMPLEMENTO = :complemento, BAIRRO = :bairro, CIDADE = :cidade, UF = :uf, CEP = :cep WHERE ID_ENDERECO = :id";
        $openConn = $this->conn->prepare($sqlCadastraEndereco);
        $openConn->bindParam(':rua', $rua);
        $openConn->bindParam(':numero', $numero);
        $openConn->bindParam(':complemento', $complemento);
        $openConn->bindParam(':bairro', $bairro);
        $openConn->bindParam(':cidade', $cidade);
        $openConn->bindParam(':uf', $uf);
        $openConn->bindParam(':cep', $cep);
        $openConn->bindParam(':id', $id);

        if($openConn->execute()){






                $result = true;

        }else{
            throw new PDOException("ERRO AO TENTAR ATUALIZAR ENDEREÇO <br />");
        }



        return $result;
    }

    public function listaEnderecoId(EnderecoModal $endereco)
    {
        // TODO: Implement listaEnderecoId() method.
    }
}
```

---

```
public function editaEndereco(EnderecoModal $endereco)
{
    $id = $endereco->getIdEndereco();
    $result = false;
    $rua = $endereco->getRua();
    $numero = $endereco->getNumResidencia();
    $bairro = $endereco->getBairro();
    $complemento = $endereco->getComplemento();
    $cidade = $endereco->getCidade();
    $uf = $endereco->getUf();
    $cep = $endereco->getCep();


    $sqlCadastraEndereco = "UPDATE  ENDERECO SET RUA = :rua, NUMERO = :numero, COMPLEMENTO = :complemento, BAIRRO = :bairro, CIDADE = :cidade, UF = :uf, CEP = :cep WHERE ID_ENDERECO = :id";
    $openConn = $this->conn->prepare($sqlCadastraEndereco);
    $openConn->bindParam(':rua', $rua);
    $openConn->bindParam(':numero', $numero);
    $openConn->bindParam(':complemento', $complemento);
    $openConn->bindParam(':bairro', $bairro);
    $openConn->bindParam(':cidade', $cidade);
    $openConn->bindParam(':uf', $uf);
    $openConn->bindParam(':cep', $cep);
    $openConn->bindParam(':id', $id);

    if($openConn->execute()){






            $result = true;

    }else{
        throw new PDOException("ERRO AO TENTAR ATUALIZAR ENDEREÇO <br />");
    }



    return $result;
}
```

Comment: Poderia colocar também o código fonte que está dando erro.

Comment: O campo `id` está com `auto_increment`? rsrsrsrs

Comment: No `try-catch` faça o PDO a mensagem de erro, com [errorinfo](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.errorinfo.php)

Comment: O id de todos é auto incremento

Comment: Vou fazer uma pergunta idiota... os dados de acesso ao servidor de banco de dados estão corretos?

Comment: Sim Estão! porque eu consigo logar e ele traz os que estao cadastrado.. So que quando vou edtar me da erro.

Comment: Verifique se o usuário que está atrelado à nova conta de mysql na hospedagem web tem permissão para todas as operações. Provavelmente o usuário de acesso ao banco só tem acesso à leitura.

Comment: Para efeito de teste, troque a linha: `throw new PDOException("ERRO AO TENTAR ATUALIZAR ENDEREÇO <br />");` por `print_r($this->conn->errorInfo());`

Comment: Me retornou isso mas nao atualizau 

Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) Array ( [0] => 00000 [1] => [2] => ) FuncionÃ¡rio atualizado com sucesso

Comment: Adicione essas duas linhas no começo do arquivo, antes dos includes, `ini_set('display_errors', true);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);`. Direto pelo banco de dados você consegue incluir/alterar registros?

Comment: Oops me desculpe, acabei me enganando aqui, seu `print_r` deve ser dessa forma: `print_r($openConn->errorInfo());`

Comment: Pessoa quero agradecer a todos vocês por tentar me ajudar. Mas eu conseguir resolver o problema e quero compartilhar aqui pra que ajude outras pessoas.
Coisa boba gente.
Eu estou usando o windows na minha maquina. Portanto, o servidor é lixux. E dai? E dai que eu estava usando o nome da tabela em caixa alta assim: ENDERECO, FUNCIONARIO, USUARIO. Ai estava o problema. O servidor linux nao aceita. Dessa forma eu coloquei normal: endereco, funcionario, usuario e funcionou lindo lindo.
Espero que ajude a outras pessoas
E a todos você obrigado.